# Looking for jQuery html projects for practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for UI projects like some application which includes Javascript, jQuery, JSON, HTML and CSS through which I can learn myself. I have been through theoretical stuff but actual knowledge comes with coding.

Comment: You could google up some tutorials, or have a look on the jQuery website for the examples that accompany their documentation.

Comment: those demos i have been through. i am looking for some assignments kinda stuff.

Comment: Start your own projects, make the usual stuff that people do and EXPAND from those. You'll soon have more stuff to do than your time allows :)  Usual stuff = Accordion, Slider, TABS, tooltip... etc. This should give you pleenty of practice.   Expanding = Put your thinking cap on to figure out improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [github](http://github.com), [google code](https://code.google.com/), [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) and others to search and look at various real or demo projects in various stages of development. In all this you can search by technology.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at:

- [codejam](https://code.google.com/codejam/)
- [rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Welcome_to_Rosetta_Code)
- [interviewstreet](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/)
- [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery)
- [and this tutorial that I think is useful](http://www.impressivewebs.com/jquery-tutorial-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 0):

A good learning for all of those techniques would be your own little chat program, something like this:

http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/